# How to integrate a function with a multidimensional constant matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I have a function,
F = exp(-B(i,j).*cos(x)) 
wherein B(i,j) is a constant matrix of dimension i-j

Now, I want to numerically integrate the above function w.r.t 'x' in an interval (0, pi/2) in Matlab.

Thanks in advance!!!

```
function Z = Z_normalization(E0,f)
%Evaluating the Normalization partition function for the calculation
%   Detailed explanation goes here
% E0 = electric field amplitude;
% f = frequency
% B(i,j) = product of electric dipole moment and field
%f = 10:100:1000000;
%E0 = [650, 750, 850, 950, 1000];
for j = 1:length(E0)
    for i = 1:length(f)
        %B(i,j) = E0(i).*f(j);
        B = Scalar_electric_potential(E0,f);
        F = @(x) exp(-B(j,i).*cos(x)).*cos(2.*x);
        Z(j,i) = integral(F, 0, pi/2)
    end
end
end
```

Here, B(i,j) is a function of f, E0 So the integration is perfectly fine when I dont have exp(F). When the exp(F) is appended the result of integration is same for all values.

Comment: Where is the difficulty? How have you tried integrating this function? What problem did you run into?

Comment: You need to work on the mathematical problem first - what method of numerical integration do you want to use?

Comment: @ Cris Luengo Thank you for the reply. I first evaluate the product B(i,j) a 3 x 3 matrix with cos (x) and then calculate the exponential. Thereafter evaluate integrate using Int(F, 0, pi.2). The problem is that the integration values are same for all functions. SO I doubt my way of integration may not be correct.

Comment: @Mekhaiil Genkin. I do understand your point, I simplify the expression as mentioned above and then intgrate it using a function called int(F, 0, pi/2)  in Matlab. But the results are having same value whenever integrates.

Comment: Any suggestions to this problem welcome!!!